# php file upload script to my website?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am trying to create a PHP file to upload images to my website. I have the following code, but it is not working. Can anyone help me fix it so I do not get any errors? Is there any better way to do such a thing? I know it is old fashioned.

```
    $uploaddir = "uploads/images";
    $allowed_ext = "jpg, JPG, png, gif";
    $max_size = "500000";
    $max_height = "4000";
    $max_width = "4000";

    $extension = pathinfo ($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $extension = $extension[extension];
    $allowed_paths = explode(", ", $allowed_ext);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($allowed_paths); $i++){
            if ($allowed_paths[$i] == "$extension"){
            $ok = "1";
        }
    }
    if ($ok == "1"){
        if($_FILES['file']['size'] > $max_size){
                print "Your file is too big!";
                exit;
            }
        }

    if($max_width && $max_height){
        list($width, $height, $type, $w) = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['name']);
        if ($width > $max_width || $height > $max_height){
                print "Your file width/height are too big!";
                exit;
            }

        }
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);

        print "Your file was uploaded successfully :)";
        }
                else
                    print "Wrong extensin";



    ?>
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
Warning: getimagesize(1 (8).jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Hosting\8923686\html\uploadedimages\upload.php on line 25

Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/images/1 (8).jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\8923686\html\uploadedimages\upload.php on line 33

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\Temp\php\phpE5F5.tmp' to 'uploads/images/1 (8).jpg' in D:\Hosting\8923686\html\uploadedimages\upload.php on line 33
```

or

```
invalid file
```

Can any one please tell me where is my problem?

Comment: Get proper permission to the files and folders you are writing to. (Line 33, where you are doing move_uploaded_file), you don't have permission to access the destination. Maybe it doesn't exist.

Comment: is any other thing than the 777 permission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getimagesize($_FILES['file']['name']` in line 25 is the first culprit: you meant `getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

For the othe errors you need to check permissions of `uploads/images` - they are obviously off limits for the webserver user.

Comment: in filezilla I gave it the 777 permission. What also should I do ?

Comment: 777 is a UNIX-style permission, which might not be applicable to the underlying Windows file system. I recommend to delete the `uploads/images`, and maybe even the `uploads` directory and to creat it from PHP in a one-off script - this way you can be sure, the webserver has the necessary privileges.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by one-off script ? how do I do such thing ?

Comment: I meant a script, that is run only once (to create the directories)

Answer (score 2):

As for the first error, change `getimagesize($_FILES['file']['name'])` to `getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])`.

As for the other two errors, make sure your script has permissions to write files to the folder where you're trying to move the uploaded file to.

**Edit:** Also try to use a full absolute path in `$uploaddir` instead of just `uploads/images`. Since you're using a relative path from a script that isn't located in the document root, it's possible that PHP is looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: I did now I am getting this:Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://www.gagsallday.com/uploadedimages/uploads/images//D:\Temp\php\php6AF0.tmp) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in D:\Hosting\8923686\html\uploadedimages\upload.php on line 33

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\Temp\php\php6AF0.tmp' to 'http://www.gagsallday.com/uploadedimages/uploads/images//D:\Temp\php\php6AF0.tmp' in D:\Hosting\8923686\html\uploadedimages\upload.php on line 33

Comment: It has to be an absolute path on the same system, not a URL. You can't move your uploaded file to a remote website. If the path differs between your development system and your live website, add some code to detect where your PHP file is running and adjust $uploaddir accordingly.